# how to divide bootstrap 4 card-body class to separate 2 columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have following bootstrap 4 card system,

```
<div class="card-body">
      <img src="{{asset('images/yimage.jpg')}}" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
      <p>This is Title of the Topic</p>
      
</div>
```

but I need divide above `card-image` class to two separate columns to 1:3 ratio and put image and topic to the columns. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstrap column structure like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
    <p>This is Title of the Topic</p>
  </div>
  </div>       
</div>
```